# Microsoft Speech-to-Text: Part of transcript missing

Tags: c#, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

In our testing of Microsoft speech-to-text for video subtitling, we sometimes (infrequently) experience "dropouts", i.e. that a chunk of the audio does not get transcribed. We do **not** get `ResultReason.NoMatch` in these cases.

The code is in C#, using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech (1.10.0). We're using `OutputFormat.Detailed` and also `speechConfig.RequestWordLevelTimestamps()`, and we use `AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput` to supply the audio.

I have a small example wav file where this is reproducible (at least with my code). Would someone be willing to run a test with their code, using the same wav file ([https://www.dropbox.com/s/delpix4wwd95iev/svensk.wav?dl=1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/delpix4wwd95iev/svensk.wav?dl=0))? I'm sorry I don't have an example in English (this is Swedish audio), but when I run this, there's a gap in the time codes (looking at the word level timestamps) between approx. 14 and 30 seconds into the audio.

Can anyone else reproduce this, or is there some obscure error in my code (which is pretty close to the example code from MS)?

Thanks in advance for any input!  :-)

Comment: I tried to run your file with the sample code of the sdk. You are right. I got only 2 different Timestamps (one for each recognized result). I don't speak swedish, so I cannot say whether the recognized text is completed or not.

Comment: Thank you! Did you also check the word-level timestamps? That's where I see about a 15 sec dropout from approx. 14 seconds into the video. If this is indeed not due to sloppy coding on my part, it's probably something Microsoft should look into...? We have seen a few such cases during our testing lately.

Comment: Yes. Proceeded with timestamps. But all `Recognizing` events return the same timestamp until the next `Recognized` event. There are two different timestamps: 10000 with sentence `Ja, men det är ett allvarligt läge i sverige som vi hörde också. Region stockholm i går som bekräftar de 18 nya dödsfall enbart under det senaste dygnet, där också antalet personer som vårdas på intensivvårdsavdelningen också bara blir fler.`

Comment: Timestamp 303200000 with sentence: `Antalet personer som vårdas på intensivvårdsavdelningen och det här gör ju också att debattklimatet om huruvida sverige gör rätt eller fel med att ha det ändå öppna samhället. Det växer.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speech runtime team has identified the cause of the issue. It is due to a misused decoder parameter. We will deploy the fix to the service within a couple of days.

-Wei

Comment: Great news; thank you so much for following up on this.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded the audio file and reproduced the same issue. The recognition results for audio from 14 to 30 seconds are missing. I am going to forward it to a related group to take a look at it. I will get back to this thread once I hear something.

Sorry for the late reply and thanks for using Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK!

-Wei